# How to highlight the argument of a certain command as verbatim in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, verbatim, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to get the argument of `\EscVerb` to become highlighted as the argument of `\verb`. I added a custom `cwl` file with the following command

`\EscVerb{verbatimSymbol}`

But this only causes the following text to become highlighted as code, not the argument itself

[image]

How to obtain proper highlighting by providing suitable `cwl` command?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document} 

\EscVerb{\\mathcal} fgfdgfdgfd

\verb|\mathcal|

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've posted a discussion under texstudio's repo: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/discussions/1951.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ. The highlighting for `\verb` argument is also done using a `cwl` file I believe, which means it is the documentation of TeXstudio needs improvement

Comment: `\verb|<code>|` and `\EscVerb{<code>}` are different syntaxes, hence perhaps the handling of `verbatimSymbol` is hardcoded to only support being delimited by two identical chars.